# Plural or singular

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

This sentence is from [IELTS-teacher Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cE1CItpngk) (time 19:01):

> A very important aspect of teaching is the ability of the teacher to shape their teaching style to the needs of their students.

My question is why *one* teacher shapes "*their* teaching style to the needs of *their* students".

If it should be *teachers*, this YouTube teacher is unreliable. We expect from a teacher to be perfect at this pretty simple English level. And if the sentence is OK, please explain to me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pronoun *they* is sometimes used to refer to one person when the author doesn't want to specify their gender as either masculine or feminine. See [Singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) at Wikipedia.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have already been dealt with.

Comment: Ok, so we should always search for duplicates before answering?

Comment: Not necessarily a tedious trawl through the archives. But here, a search for the obvious 'data + plural' rapidly turns up the original. Assume that a lot of questions have already been asked.